# Remove timezone info in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

Hello all pandas experts.
I am trying to remove time zone info string from a pandas column. I just need the date and time. Here's what I did:

```
from datetime import datetime

df['created_at'] = pd.to_datetime(df['created_at']).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d H%:M%:S%')
```

Instead, I got this error msg.

```
ParserError: Unknown string format: 2021-08-01 22:47:19 Malay Peninsula Standard Time
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: pls feel free to comment if you think that the question is wrongly closed

Comment: Tried also this but still getting error.


`df['created_at'] = df['created_at'].dt.tz_localize(None)`


Error msg

`AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values`

Comment: convert to datetime first `pd.to_datetime(df['created_at']).dt.tz_localize(None)`

Comment: Got this error. `ParserError: Unknown string format: 2021-08-01 22:47:19 Malay Peninsula Standard Time`. Need to strip out the timezone string first.

Comment: pass `errors='coerce'` in `to_datetime()` method `pd.to_datetime(df['created_at'],error='corece').dt.tz_localize(None)` if you again get any error then updated your question with a sample dataframe and your expected output from it

Comment: Finally found the solution. `df["created_at"] = [re.sub(r'[^0-9-:\s+]','', created_at.rstrip()) for created_at in df['created_at']]` and then
`df["created_at"] = pd.to_datetime(df['created_at'])` Thanks anyways.